# Changing autosave option in enthought canopy ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, enthought, undo, canopy, autosave

The ipython notebook editor in Enthough Canopy's installation Autosaves every 2 min or so. The undo feature (i.e. cmd + z) cannot be used to go beyond the Autosave (http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/release-notes.html#resolved-undo-goes-too-far-back-858).

Is it possible to change the time between Autosaves?

This would lessen the likelihood of, for example, deleting you code, realizing your screw-up and then being unable to undo what you did due to an unwanted Autosave.